# How to resize text in libGDX

Tags: java, android, fonts, libgdx, resize

I want to be able to draw a letter or a text segment that occupies a certain width and height in my screen. I couldn't find anything except the FreeType extension that enables me to change the size of the font, but that's not what I want. I want to be able to transform the text with the width and height I want. ( I'm developing for android devices, that's why I want to be able to do that, or else I'm going to resort to images for every word and number xc).

Comment: You might want to look into distance field fonts: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Distance-field-fonts

Comment: I think that is not what I'm looking for. I want to set a text, like a string, and then print it with the preferred width and height.

Comment: If you use a Scene2D label like suggested in the answer below you can scale your text. But it will look blurry because of the filtering. That's where the distance field fonts come in. I guess I was one step to far!

Answer (score 0):

Put the text into a [Label](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Label.html). Labels allow you to set the font scale.

Alternately, use a BitmapFont and [BitmapFontCache](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/BitmapFontCache.html)

Comment: I don't want to change the font scale, I want to change the width and height of the region in which the text is drawn. I want to be able to stretch and/or shrink the text. (to fit the screen, for example).

Comment: Have you tried using a BitmapFontCache? It allows setting the text size and position.

http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/BitmapFontCache.html

Comment: So, if I want to change the size of the text in a label I call this function "setFontScaleX and/or setFontScaleY" ?